# Compare two dicts and update the dict based on the compared dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

Solution for Compare two dict and update the dict based on compared dict

compare dict1 with dict2 and update the dict1 based on the dict key values,here "id" is the unique key

```
dict1={id:1,mobile:'nokia',count:54,size:9}

dict2={id:1,mobile:'nokia',count:63,size:9}
```

expected output:

```
dict1={id:1,mobile:'nokia',count:63,size:9}
```

Comment: What should the comparison do? This is probably just `dict1.update(dict2)`.

Comment: Before comparing these dict,Need to iterate the the "id" which means check the "dict1" id= "dict" id and update the "dict1" values from "dict2"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code:

```
dict1={"id":1,"mobile":'nokia',"count":54,"size":9}

dict2={"id":1,"mobile":'nokia',"count":63,"size":9}

dict1.update(dict2)

print(dict1)
```

Output:

```
{'id': 1, 'mobile': 'nokia', 'count': 63, 'size': 9}
```